# Aggregate documents in MongoDB of double nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am trying to count documents with different conditions. Here I have such simplified table of texts(documents):

```
{ 
  "teamId": "1",
  "stage": "0",
  "answeredBy": [userId_1, userId_2],
  "skippedBy": [userId_3],
  "answers": []
},
{ 
  "teamId": "1",
  "stage": "0",
  "answeredBy": [userId_2],
  "skippedBy": [userId_1],
  "answers": []
},
{ 
  "teamId" : "1",
  "stage": "0",
  "answeredBy": [userId_3],
  "skippedBy": [userId_2],
  "answers": []
},
{ 
  "teamId" : "1",
  "stage": "1",
  "answeredBy": [userId_3],
  "skippedBy": [userId_1, userId_2],
  "answers": [
              { "readBy": [userId_1] },
              { "readBy": [userId_1, userId_2] },
              { "readBy": [userId_3, userId_1] },       
  ]
},
{ 
  "teamId" : "1",
  "stage": "1",
  "answeredBy": [userId_3],
  "skippedBy": [userId_1, userId_2],
  "answers": [
              { "readBy": [userId_1] },
              { "readBy": [userId_1, userId_2] },
              { "readBy": [userId_3] },       
  ]
};
```

And I want to count in one query per appropriate user Id, stage and teamID (so first $match must be per teamId and stages: "0" or "1":

- **how many documents on stage: "0" contains userID in answeredBy OR skippedBy arrays (I called this Document "Answered")**
- **how many documents on stage: "0" doesn't contain userID both in answeredBy AND in skippedBy arrays (I called this Document "Unanswered")**
- **how many documents with stage: "1" have in answers array at least ONE array readBy which doesn't contains user (I called it "UnRead" Document)**

So I tried to achieve it in many ways, but the most difficult part is to iterate through nested arrays (**readBy**) of array **answers** and find which one doesn't contain appropriate user and count this document as **UNREAD**.

Possible results:

```
 {
   answered: 2,
   unanswered: 1,
   unread: 1,
 };
```

or

```
 [
   { _id: 'answered', count: 2 },
   { _id: 'unanswered', count: 1 },
   { _id: 'unread', count: 1 }
 ]
```

I am stuck after writing this query and don't know how to iterate through readBy arrays:

```
db.texts.aggregate([
      { $match: {teamId: 1, $or: [{currStage: 0}, {currStage: 1}]}},
      { $project: { 'stage': { $switch: { branches: [
      { case: 
             { $and: [ { $eq: [ '$currStage', 0 ] },
             { $not: [ { $or: [ { $in: [ userId_1, '$answeredBy' ] },
             { $in: [ userId_1, '$skippedBy' ] } ] } ] } ] },
        then: 'unanswered'},
      { case: 
             { $and: [ { $eq: [ '$currStage', 0 ] },
             { $or: [ { $in: [ userId_1, '$answeredBy' ] },
             { $in: [ userId_1, '$skippedBy' ] } ] } ] },
        then: 'answered'},
      { case:
             { $and: [ { $eq: [ '$currStage', 1 ] },
             { $not: [ { $in: [ userId_1, '$answers.readBy' ] } ] } ] },
        then: 'unread'},
                 ] } } } },
      { $group: { _id: '$stage', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
 ]);
```

Comment: What are the criteria's for these conditions. `how many texts was answered or skipped (I called it "Answered")
how many texts was unanswered or not skipped (I called it "Unanswered")
how many texts has all answers read by set user (I called it "Read")` Could you explain which field we can take for `unanswered`, `skipped` and `Read`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have user id (currently userId_1). So I want to count for this appropriate user how many texts he answered/skipped and have at least one answer UNread( I made a mistake, not read)

Comment: ok so for answered i will look into `answeredBy` and for unread `answers.readBy` and for skipped i will look into `skippedBy`?

Comment: yes exists in `answeredBy` or `skippedBy` and `answers.readBy` (the biggest issue that I need to check all `readBy` arrays of one text(document  of the collection)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I am kindly asking you to look again on my opened Question(Issue) I made few changes in expected results. I am sorry for these inconveniences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution. Thank you for everyone who tried to solve it and helped me.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $match: {teamId: "1", $or: [{stage: "0"}, {stage: "1", "answers": {$elemMatch: {"readBy": {$nin: ["userId_1"]}}}}]}},
  { $project: { 'stage': { $switch: { branches: [
  { case: 
         { $and: [ { $eq: [ '$stage', "0" ] },
         { $not: [ { $or: [ { $in: [ "userId_1", '$answeredBy' ] },
         { $in: [ "userId_1", '$skippedBy' ] } ] } ] } ] },
    then: 'unanswered'},
  { case: 
         { $and: [ { $eq: [ '$stage', "0" ] },
         { $or: [ { $in: [ "userId_1", '$answeredBy' ] },
         { $in: [ "userId_1", '$skippedBy' ] } ] } ] },
    then: 'answered'},
  { case:
         { $eq: [ '$stage', "1" ] } ,
    then: 'unread'},
             ] } } } },
  { $group: { _id: '$stage', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
])
```

Maybe I should find a better solution, but currently this is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

try this, I am assuming userid = `userId_1`

```
db.getCollection('answers').aggregate([
      { $match: {teamId: '1', $or: [{stage: '0'}, {stage: '1'}]}},
      {$project:{
          counts :{$cond: [
              {$or:[{$in:["userId_1", "$answeredBy"]}, {$in:["userId_1", "$skippedBy"]}]}, 
              {$literal:{answered: 1, unaswered: 0}}, 
              {$literal:{answered: 0, unaswered: 1}}
          ]},
          unread : {$cond:[
                  {$gt:[{$reduce: {
                      input: "$answers", 
                      initialValue: 1, 
                      in: {$multiply:["$$value", 
                          {$cond:[
                              {$in:["userId_1", "$$this.readBy"]},
                              {$literal: 0},
                              {$literal: 1}
                           ]}
                       ]}}},
                       0
                     ]},
                     {$literal: 1},
                     {$literal: 0}
               ]}

      }},
      {$group: {_id: null, answered: {$sum: "$counts.answered"}, unanswered: {$sum: "$counts.unanswered"}, unread: {$sum: "$unread"}}}
])
```

Comment: This solution looks interesting, but doesn't provide me necessary result. For example after running your query for current db I got result: `{"_id":null,"answered":5,"unanswered":0,"read":2}`. So according to your answer I have **7** documents in the collection, but I have only **5**.

Comment: And I didn't see where you looked for "userId_1" in each array - this is the main task, to find where this user exists

Comment: I am printing the same comment as for other proposed solution.
Your solution count both last documents of the collection as read, when one of the documents doesn't include userId_1 in each readBy array. So when at least One readBy array doesn't include userId_1 - it is unread Document

Comment: I am kindly asking you to look again on my opened Question(Issue) I made few changes in expected results. I am sorry for these inconveniences.

Comment: Here is result what I got after running your query: `{"_id":null,"answered":4,"unanswered":0,"unread":3}`. It is not what I expected. I guess I wasn't clear in my question. 
Edited it again. Maybe now will be clearer. I am sorry again. I don't have much experience in posting questions here.

Comment: Expected results from the main Question:
First $match must be per teamId and stages: "0" or "1". After counter:
 - **how many documents on stage: "0" contains userID in answeredBy OR skippedBy arrays (I called this Document "Answered")**
 - **how many documents on stage: "0" doesn't contain userID both in answeredBy AND in skippedBy arrays (I called this Document "Unanswered")**
 - **how many documents with stage: "1" have in answers array at least ONE array readBy which doesn't contains user (I called it "UnRead" Document)**